# How to convert a calendar event description into a dictionary object in iPhone?

Tags: ios, ios6, ekevent, ekeventkit

I am fetching the Events from the calendar and for each event i want to fetch all the data. But i am getting some of them as objects like EKRecurrenceRule, EkCalendar, EKAlarm.
Now i want to get a particular field from the object.
I tried converting the object into a Dictionary object but it goes as a single object and when i access it it returns a single value with the entire object.
Can anybody help me converting them directly into dictionary.

Comment: You can't convert an `EKCalendar`, for example, into an `NSDictionary` because it isn't one. All of the values that you can get at are properties of the object; just fetch them with dot-notation or a method call.

Comment: what about EKRecurrence ? It returns me an array, and still i am not able to access it. It gives me a null value when i access it like this ,
NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithArray:e.recurrenceRules];
        NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:arr forKey:@"dict"];
        NSLog(@"Interval : %@",[dict valueForKey:@"INTERVAL"]);

Comment: You don't need a dictionary to just access object's properties. Read description of EKEvent class to see what properties are available.

Comment: Yes, i saw the class reference and everything. The problem is i am backing up my events data from iPhone and pushing onto the server, and i want to catch this data at the android side. So i cannot pass the data directly cause it is not recognised at android side.

Also i dont have to use any 3rd party servers like google for syncing.

So i want to separate out the data.
I am getting recurrence rules as an array and i am asking how can i access values from it seperately to store it individually.

Comment: in that case - create NSDictionary manually and copy all needed properties

Answer (score 0):

use **KVC** for that... `valueForKey` and `valueForKeyPath` allow you treat the object 'kind of like a dictionary'

Comment: i tried doing it ...
and for the first instance i am getting the entire object
EKRecurrenceRule <0x18b0f0> RRULE FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR

That means it did not get seperated when i pushed it into a dictionary object..

Comment: what you should here is the description of the rule object itself

Comment: everything is  'splitted up' there for you